# Accessing computed array from one component in another using VueX

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

In one component I have this function that is being updated within that component:

```
 computed: {
    //filter based on dates
    mapfiltered: function() {
      return this.mapped.filter(i => this.y.includes(i.date));
    },
}
```

Now in another component I want to access this `mapfiltered` computed property.

```
           <single-news-template
                  v-for="m in mapfiltered"
                  v-bind:key="m.id"
                  v-bind:title="m.title"
                ></single-news-template>
```

I think its possible with VueX but im not sure how can I modify it, so that it could be accessed

Comment: You can simply put a `ref="original"` on your original component and then use `this.$refs.original.mapfiltered` to get the computed property in your other component. If you insist on using Vuex - then you should convert your computed property into a Vuex getter.

Comment: Where should I put this ref="original"? In the comopnent tag when I use it in the html?

Comment: Yes, like this `<another-component-template><div><original-component ref="original">...</original-component></div></another-component-template>`